# How to automate Google Play Update App popup using Appium

Tags: appium, ui-automation, appium-android, appium-java

I am writing the code line as:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.vending:id/0_resource_name_obfuscated")).click();
//Clicking on No Thanks button - resourceid take from Ui Automator
```

But appium does not respond to this line and give error that no element found.
"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters"

Any help? Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tapping on No Thanks, I used back button

driver.navigate().back();

Query has been resolved with alternate method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wait methods :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.id("com.android.vending:id/0_resource_name_obfuscated")));
//Or use condition: elementToBeClickable()
```